# how to match similar domains in adblock custom filtering

Tags: regex, adblock

I am accessing a website which gradually increments its domain name:

```
http://mywebsite100.com/
```

then

```
http://mywebsite101.com/
```

and so on...

I wrote a rule to block ads on all upcoming domain names but adblock wouldn't accept such syntax.

```
mywebsite*.com##UL[class="myclass"]
```

here is the documention of adblock custom filtering: https://adblockplus.org/en/filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Adblock Plus filter consists of two parts: a pattern to select what should be blocked and a list of domains on which the filter should be applied (among many other options that you can specify).

Request blocking filters can define a regular expression

e.g. `/^http:\/\/mysite\d+\.com\/$domain=example.com`

Element hiding filters use CSS selectors

e.g. `example.com##a[href^="http://mysite"][href*=".com"]`

Note that the domain list (in this case "example.com") has to be static. So the best way to hide elements on such domains is to restrict it to the domain `com` and make the CSS selector as specific as you can so that it will only match on the pages you'd like to target.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://mywebsite\d+.com/ its a JavaScript Regular Expression.
Yeah i just tried it too. Its valid but it doesn't seem to do anything. I think you have to include all the numbers in your filter. The reason I say this is because the list that ABP is using has to list out all the different countries domains for, for example, amazon.com. Like en de au for the different country codes in the world. I've noticed a lot of these blocking sites have a lot of data in them and even though regular expressions are allowed theres still a LOT of data in these files.

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you can't use Regular Expression Characters in the Domain part of the code.

Below Microsoft Article provides an example of invalid use of * in Domain part.
The second one is invalid, as the article states, "because the wildcard is used in the domain part of the domain rule" (1)

+d contoso.com sub*string
+d contoso*.com substring

(1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273399(v=vs.85).aspx#creatingtpls

Comment: it returns an error:   The following filter:
http://mywebsite\d+.com##DIV[class="FooerBottom"] 
has an error: 
Invalid domain: http://mywebsite\d+.com

Comment: It's an error because you can't have regular expression characters in the domain name part of the expression. You have a \d+ before the string .com so the expression is invalid.